# Magento 2: Product showing out of stock if default source has 0 qty in Multi Source Inventory

Tags: magento2, multi-source-inventory

I need to use MSI (Multi source inventory) feature but i notice that if qty is 0 in default source then
product is going to out of stock even qty is already available in other source so how can i solve this?
i need to showing the product IN stock if any source store have the qty.

any idea, please share.

Comment: Me too facing this same issue. Have u found the reason for this issue?

Comment: Out of stock & in Stock is only use the Default Source qty. So you have to assign the qty to that source also. We did not found anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue, did anyone find a solution? we still have stock in second warehouse for a product thats now showing out of stock